# How can we clear the state in Flink based on an external event?

Tags: apache-flink

I am working on simple case where we join a Stream 1 (Positions) with Stream 2 (Price) and links the latest Position data with price data.
To do this I am extending a RichCoFlatMapFunction, It builds a wrapper object which collects the data from either streams.
In the process it also stores the data in its MapState.

At the end of day, based on another stream data (e.g. date change stream), I need to clear the states.
How can i do that? 
Basically i need to clear the priceState and positionState. I am not sure if we can get a broadcast stream to do that?

Sample code for joining 2 streams is below

```
static final class PositionPriceWrapperBuilder extends RichCoFlatMapFunction<Position, Price, PositionPriceWrapper> {



    private transient MapState<String, Price>  priceState;
    private transient MapState<String, Position>  positionState;        

    @Override
    public void open(Configuration parameters) throws Exception {


        MapStateDescriptor<String, Price>  descPrice = new MapStateDescriptor<String, Price>(
                "priceState",
                String.class,
                Price.class);           
        priceState = getRuntimeContext().getMapState(descPrice);                
        System.out.println("descPrice:: " + descPrice);
        //Same thing needs to be done for Price?


        MapStateDescriptor<String, Position>  descPos = new MapStateDescriptor<String, Position>(
                "positionState",
                String.class,
                Position.class);            
        positionState = getRuntimeContext().getMapState(descPos);               
        System.out.println("positionState:: " + positionState);

    }           

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public void flatMap1(Position position, Collector<PositionPriceWrapper> out) throws Exception {
          try {
              //= pnlState.get(position.getId());
              Price price = priceState.get(position.getId());
              PositionPriceWrapper ppw = new PositionPriceWrapper();
              ppw.setPrice(price);
              ppw.setPosition(position);
              ppw.setAccount(position.getAccount());
              ppw.setCusip(position.getCusip());

              System.out.println("Built ppw -->" + ppw);

              positionState.put(position.getId(), position);
              out.collect(ppw);
          }
          catch ( Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }

    }

    @Override
    public void flatMap2(Price price, Collector<PositionPriceWrapper> out) throws Exception {
          try {
              Position position = positionState.get(price.getId());
              PositionPriceWrapper ppw = new PositionPriceWrapper();
              ppw.setPrice(price);
              ppw.setPosition(position);
              ppw.setAccount(price.getAccount());
              ppw.setCusip(price.getCusip());

              priceState.put(price.getId(), price);
              out.collect(ppw);
          }
          catch ( Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }         

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do would be straightforward if Flink offered a three-input operator, but it does not. Flink only supports operators with one or two inputs.

One option might be to transform your RichCoFlatMap into a CoProcessFunction, and use a timer to trigger state clearing. Or rely on the [StateTTL](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.8/dev/stream/state/state.html#state-time-to-live-ttl) mechanism to clear the state.

If you do need to explicitly trigger state clearing, what you could do would be to use union() to merge the price and position streams into a `DataStream<Either<Price, Position>>` (or map both streams to some unified type first) and then connect that stream to a broadcast stream that has the signals that initiate state clearing. Or you could union all three streams together if they are all going to be keyed in the same way.